# Python: passing parameter to background process

Tags: python, linux

I'm looking for better solution for my problem.

I need to run python script and then while it is running (in background) I need to change a value inside, whenever user want to do it. It can happen up to 20 times an hour or even more but there will be periods of time when nothing will happen. So changing has to be as clean as possible.

I'm working on following background. I have two scripts: starter and main.
Task of the main script is to set serial connection and to communicate with external device and this process is running as `nohup main.py &` - after start it would probably be running until reboot.
Task of the starter script is to just start main if there is no additional argument. Main is running in background and starter is closing.

If there is additional argument I want to "connect" with already running main and send value of this argument to it. I'm currently using external file 'last.cfg' to exchange data but is there any 'nicer' solution? I have read about multiprocessing module and using pipes but I couldn't fit this to my needs. Probably I have not seen something important.

---

Current approach example (I have cut off any not necessary code):

**main.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        f = open("./desktop/last.cfg","r+")
        contents = f.readline()
        print(contents)
```

**starter.py**

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("val", nargs='?', default="null")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.val == 'null':
    sub = subprocess.Popen("nohup ./desktop/main.py &", shell=True)
else:
    f = open("./desktop/last.cfg","r+")
    content = f.readline()
    p = re.compile('(val=)([0-9]*)')
    content = p.sub('\g<1>'+args.val,content)
    f.close()
    f = open("./desktop/last.cfg","w+")
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Where do you need to change a value? Inside where? The script that is running or some other file? If you need to change the value of a variable in the script, just do `x = 'variable`. More clarification is needed in your post

Comment: @ycx
 _I need to run python script and then while it is running (in background) I need to change a value inside, whenever user want to do it._ (...)
_Task of the main script is to set serial connection and to communicate with external device_ (...)
_Task of the starter script is to just start main if there is no additional argument_ (...)
_If there is additional argument I want to "connect" with already running main and send value of this argument to it._

Change inside main, by other script.
Any better mechanism to exchange data between two scripts is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So what you basically want is a way to change some value in the running Python script from outside. I would argue that your file approach is the easiest and the best one, and this is what regular software uses all the time (configuration files that are being reloaded when needed). I don't think you need to go to shared memory, FIFOs, network sockets, or whatever else can be used, to achieve what you need. Simplicity pays off.

There can be simple improvements to your file approach that will make it look not that bad at all. First of all, don't read the file all the time, but read it only if needed. You can achieve it by checking the file's modification time once in a while using `stat` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html)) and read it only if the modification time has changed. Alternatively, you can do the same thing that Linux daemons normally do: re-read your configuration upon receiving `SIGHUP`. Example of signal handling is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example), you'll probably need `SIGHUP`, not `SIGALRM` as in example. To send `SIGHUP` signal to your process, use `kill -HUP pid`, where `pid` is the process ID as shown by `ps -a`.